# How can I search for paragraph marks?

Tags: google-docs

In MS Word, I do a search for `^p`

Is there a similar search string that I could use in Google Docs to find paragraph marks?

I do that kind of search, by the way, to replace 3 paragraph marks with 2.

Answer (score 4):

In Google Doc open the search box (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>), then click on *More options* icon, check *Match using regular expressions* checkbox, and search for `\n`.

Comment: This was launched in 2016: [Use regular expressions to search in Google Docs
Tuesday, September 27, 2016](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2016/09/use-regular-expressions-to-search-in.html)